# How do I sort two arrays without altering the original ones or mallocing new ones?

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, malloc

To make things simple, here's an example of what I want to do:

Say we have two arrays, A and B;

A = [5, 5, 5, 9, 1]

B = [9, 5, 1, 4, 4]

In the program, there are hundreds of these small arrays. I'm trying to sort them based on their maximum values. So in this case, they both have 9's, so go to the next biggest number. Okay, they both have fives, next number. The A array has a 5, and the B array has a 4, so the A array would be sorted first. The problem here is that I don't know how to sort these guys without mallocing a new array to sort these values.

Here's what I got:

```
int compare(const void *x, const void *y)
{
struct Data *s1, *s2;
s1 = (struct Data *)x;
s2 = (struct Data *)y;

int maxv=-1000;
int maxv2=-1000;
int maxvn=1000;
int maxv2n=1000;


int j=0;
int k=0;

for (k=0; k < 5;k++)
{
max = -1000;
max2= -1000;
    for (j=0; j<5;j++)
    {
        if (s1->margin[j]>max && s1->margin[j]<maxvn)
            maxv=s1->margin[j];
        if (s2->margin[j]>max2 && s2->margin[j]<maxv2n)
            maxv2=s2->margin[j];
    }
if (max2<max)
    return 1;
if (max<max2)
    return -1;

maxvn=maxv;
maxv2n=maxv2;
}
return 0;
}
```

So, in theory, I want array A to be listed before array B. Unfortunately, array B is being listed before array A because of (i think) the second condition in this argument:

```
if (s1->margin[j]>max && s1->margin[j]<maxvn)
```

The other two 5's in the array A are being ignored because of the second argument.

Now, I have no idea how to actually fix this problem unless I just malloc some arrays and then bubble sort them. This though slows my program down. Can anyone here think of a fix that I can implement that would prevent me from using any sort of mallocs and doesn't overlook recurring numbers?

Thanks.

Comment: These arrays you want to sort are all exactly length 5, yes?

Comment: And are you sorting an array of arrays (i.e. a 2D array) or an array of pointers to arrays?  It makes little difference in how you compare them, but a big difference in how you swap them.

Comment: They are all length 5.

Comment: Can you assume small bounds on the array elements, such as applies to your example data?

Comment: Yes this is important: if your "small" arrays are stored in an array of arrays, it is different.

Comment: They're pointers to structures each with an array in them.

Comment: Can you assume small bounds on the array elements, such as applies to your example data? Yes. They will never be large.

Comment: But is this a set of pointers (to the structures with array), or an array of pointers (to the structures with array)? I mean do you have a `struct Data *my_arrays[N];`?

Comment: Are you sorting the contents of each array? or are you sorting multiple arrays,  given some criteria?  If sorting multiple arrays, what is the sort criteria?   Perhaps use a bubble sort for individual arrays  then use a loop that starts at the end of the array and works backwards to determine which of the arrays is larger.

Comment: What is the maximum value of a single value in the array? Is it 9 as you show in your example?

Answer (score 3):

There are at least two possible approaches.  The more general is to declare work arrays on the stack, copy the originals into these work arrays, sort them, and then compare them.  This avoids the expense and complexity of `malloc()` and gains you simple(-ish) element comparisons.  It still uses auxilliary space.  Example:

```
int compare(const void *x, const void *y)
{
    struct Data *s1 = (struct Data *) x;
    struct Data *s2 = (struct Data *) y;
    int temp1[5];  /* or replace `int` with the correct type */
    int temp2[5];  /* or replace `int` with the correct type */
    int i;

    memcpy(temp1, s1->margin, sizeof(temp1));
    memcpy(temp2, s2->margin, sizeof(temp2));

    /* ... sort temp1 and temp2 however you want ... */

    /* compare */
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i += 1) {
        if (temp1[i] < temp2[i]) return -1;
        if (temp1[i] > temp2[i]) return  1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively, if the array elements have small enough bounds then you can compute a key value for each and compare them.  This particular one works if the array elements are all certain to be between `0` and `20`, inclusive:

```
int compare(const void *x, const void *y)
{
    struct Data *s1 = (struct Data *) x;
    struct Data *s2 = (struct Data *) y;
    uint64_t key1 = 0;
    uint64_t key2 = 0;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i += 1) {
        key1 += 1 << (s1->margin[i] * 3);
        key2 += 1 << (s2->margin[i] * 3);
    }

    if (key1 < key2) return -1;
    if (key1 > key2) return  1;
    return 0;
}
```

That treats the keys as arrays of 3-bit elements, and accumulates in each element the number of times that element's index appears in the corresponding original array.  The resulting 64-bit values can be compared via ordinary integer comparison operators.

If the elements of your original array are bounded between `0` and `9` then 32-bit keys would be sufficient for this second approach.

**Updated to add:**

Note, too, that if you have a large number of these arrays to sort then it would be greatly to your advantage to minimize the cost of your comparisons.  The computed-key approach has the advantage that you could compute a key for each array just once, store it somewhere, and then have very fast comparisons for the rest of the sort.  Any type of temp array or multi-loop approach within the individual comparisons will be very rough on your performance (and even re-computing the keys each time, though not terrible, is also not great).

Comment: 5 element arrays could be sorted using a [sorting network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_network) consisting of 9 if / swap statements. If it turns out that sorting the array of pointers to structs is taking too long, a merge sort could be considered, since it does fewer compares of the structs than quick sort (not sure about heap sort), but more moves of the pointers, but that would require allocating a second array of pointers for the merge sort.

Comment: Yes, a sorting network would be a good way to perform those sorts of the temp arrays.  Even with that, however, the computed-key approach is going to beat the temp-array approach, even with the keys re-computed for each comparison.  If the keys are computed once for each array and retained, on the other hand, then the resulting comparison performance would be pretty hard to beat.

Comment: If the range of the integers allows the keys to be used, and if it's ok to create an array of keys, and if the structs are an array of structs, then an array of pointers to structs can be converted into an array of pointers to keys and vice versa, using (array_of_pointer[i] - &array_type1[0]) to generate an index, then adding &array_type1[0] to convert to pointer of type2. The array of pointers to structs would be converted to array of pointers to keys, then sorted, then converted back into array of pointers to structures. The compare routine would only need to know the pointer type.

Answer (score 0):

You could allocate one additional element in each array and store in that element the largest value contained in the array.  Then whenever the array is updated the code that does the update could keep the max value slot if needed.  You'd always have the array's highest value in say slot 0 (or slot 5 for instance if the arrays always contained 5 elements).

It's the classic speed vs size trade off in performance.  One additional element's RAM footprint per array plus time to keep max element updates vs. complexity of sorting arrays or scanning through them serially.

Answer (score -1):

First, sort all of the small arrays (either with qsort(), or if they are very small, your own bubble or insertion sort might be faster) to make the comparison easier. This will make your compare function smaller. Then simplify your compare() function (now it only needs to make one simultaneous pass through both arrays), and use qsort() on the array of arrays passing it your new compare() function.

Comment: He says he must not modify the small arrays, so sorting them is right out.